# Hi, I am new to Power BI. So, any help will be appreciated. I have a table having 2 different values which have 2 ID

Tags: powerbi

I am new to Power BI. So, any help will be appreciated. I have a table name LISTID having 2 different values which have 2 different ID.

I have 2 table which source from O data and I connect to List which uses the ID.

How can I use LISTID first value as parameter in one table as a parameter in source and the second value in second table as a source.

I am not able to figure it out. I converted the table to list but I can't reference different values as parameters in different table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not clear what you need to achive

Comment: Show some sample data and expected output for understanding

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, help us help you by asking a question in the right way. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It may help to show some example data, and expected outcomes